# ExtJS 4.1 - How to add items to toolbar dynamically?

Tags: extjs4, toolbar, extjs4.1

I'm trying to minimize windows as a button at a taskbar - which is actually a toolbar but I couldn't add button dynamically to the taskbar. I tried calling `doLayout()` function but it didn't work either.

Here's what I tried - any help will be appreciated a lot!

Thanks in advance.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     this.addListener('show', function(win) {
          taskbar.add(me.taskButton);
          taskbar.doLayout();
     });
</script>
```

Variables :

- **win** : The window that will be minimized
- **taskbar** : A toolbar that is rendered at south region of my viewport

Comment: It should work fine with just `add`. I would look into how the listener is getting attached, inspect the DOM in firebug (or equivalent) and verify that it _is_ getting attached. Also what does your `taskButton` config look like? Is the `taskButton` getting created with `Ext.create` before you are trying to add it to the toolbar?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, **taskButton** is a simple **Button** component:

    this.taskButton = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
                       text : me.title,
                       handler : function(btn) {
                        me.show();
                       }
                      });

I create it inside of window definition(in **initComponent** function) but it's not important at all.. I can define them one by one. The way to add items dynamically to the toolbar is enough for me.

Comment: Is your event handler getting fired? Try adding `console.log(win)` in the function and see if anything comes out when you show your window.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very sure that you do not need to do `doLayout` when you use component `add`. The framework already do the rendering for you so there is no need to do the `doLayout` again.

I suspect that your event listener is not being attached correctly. Check out my working example as below:

http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/sHrGH/